# AVspeechSynthesizer iOS text speech

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, text-to-speech, avspeechsynthesizer

i am new to swift and iOS application development. I am creating a text to speech application using the AVSpeechSynthesiser. I am  wanting to set a string say in English but i am wanting it to translate that particular string to speech but in a different language such as Arabic. Am I able to do this using the AVSpeechSynthesizer, or would i need to use a translation API to do this.

ThankYou

Comment: You would need to translate the string prior to feeding it to `AVSpeechSynthesizer`

Comment: hi thank you for your reply. what API can i use to translate the string before feeding it into the AVSpeechSynthesizer. Does Apple have its own APIs to support this.

Comment: You can often find things by digging around on GitHub. I saw this https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/ios-sdk#language-translator, but I haven't used it. Google and Bing will do translation. Here's a framework that does it--> https://github.com/gpolak/FGTranslator. You'll bump into CocoaPods a lot when using frameworks, so here's a tutorial on them--> https://www.raywenderlich.com/97014/use-cocoapods-with-swift

Comment: When using translation frameworks, there will often be a rate cap on how many characters/words you can translate for free before you have to start paying for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I threw together an AVSpeechSynthesizer class to handle flipping from one language to another. Here's a [AVSpeechSynthesizer tutorial on NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/avspeechsynthesizer/) that's a good starting point for learning about this. I haven't fiddled with translation, but you can figure that part out...I also created a basic translator class that'll translate "hello" to "مرحبا". You can see the project here:

[TranslateDemo](https://github.com/AdrianBinDC/TranslateDemo)

To use the translator, you'd probably want to tie an action to a button like so:

```
@IBAction func translateToArabicAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // check that there are characters entered in the textField
    if (textToTranslateTextField.text?.characters.count)! > 0 {
        let translatedText = translator.translate(word: (textToTranslateTextField.text?.lowercased())!)
        speechSynthesizer.speak(translatedText, in: Language.arabic.rawValue)
    }
}

@IBAction func translateToEnglishAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // check that there are characters entered in the textField
    if (textToTranslateTextField.text?.characters.count)! > 0 {
        let translatedText = translator.translate(word: (textToTranslateTextField.text?.lowercased())!)
        speechSynthesizer.speak(translatedText, in: Language.english.rawValue)
    }
}
```

The speech synthesizer looks like this:

```
import AVFoundation

// You can use an enum so you don't have to manually type out character strings. Look them up once and stick them in an enum. From there, you set the language with your enum rather than typing out the string.
enum Language: String {
    case english = "en-US"
    case arabic = "ar-SA"
}

class Speaker: NSObject {

    let synth = AVSpeechSynthesizer()

    override init() {
        super.init()
        synth.delegate = self
    }

    func speak(_ announcement: String, in language: String) {
        print("speak announcement in language \(language) called")
        prepareAudioSession()
        let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: announcement.lowercased())
        utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: language)
        synth.speak(utterance)
    }

    private func prepareAudioSession() {
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient, with: .mixWithOthers)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    func stop() {
        if synth.isSpeaking {
            synth.stopSpeaking(at: .immediate)
        }
    }
}

extension Speaker: AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate {
    func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, didStart utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {
        print("Speaker class started")
    }

    func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, didFinish utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {
        print("Speaker class finished")
    }
}
```

Comment: ThankYou for creating the exemplary code. It is much appreciated.  I have decided to not use a translator as there are only a certain few strings i need to translate and i can use the example you have given in order to translate them myself. I wanted to ask could i use a  similar function for speech to text, is that possible?. Thanks again for you help.